# Haskell if then else with "two statements"

Tags: haskell

How can I do this:

```
if n > 0
then putStrLn "Hello"
     putStrLn "Anything"
```

I want to have "two statements" in one condition but I keep getting compilation errors

I tried using semi-colon with no luck

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`then` can only take one value....  But you are in luck, because `do` smashes multiple `IO()` values into one....

```
if n > 0
  then do
    putStrLn "Hello"
    putStrLn "Anything"
  else return ()
```

Remember, in Haskell, you need an `else` also (and `return ()` creates the trivial `IO()` that does nothing).

Comment: If you don't like the `else return ()` you can use `when` from `Control.Monad` instead of `if .. then ... else ...`.

Answer (score 6):

Your example wouldn't make sense in Haskell. Every expression needs to have a value, which is why you always need to have an `else`, even if it is just `return ()`.

Because it needs to be a single expression, you can't just do

```
putStrLn "Hello"
putStrLn "Anything"
```

since those are two expressions of type `IO ()`, which means it is a computatinon with some external effects, and that there is no result. You have two computations that need to run in a sequence, which can be done using the `>>` combinator

```
putStrLn "Hello" >> putStrLn "Anything"
```

There is also an alternative syntax using the `do` block.

```
do
  putStrLn "Hello"
  putStrLn "Anything"
```

The important thing to note here is that **this will compile to the same `>>` code as the example above.** The `do` block can be thought of just as syntactic sugar (there is more to it, but for simplicity you can think of it that way.)

Putting this all together leaves us with

```
if n > 0
then putStrLn "Hello" >> putStrLn "Anything"
else return ()
```

or using the do block

```
if n > 0
then do
  putStrLn "Hello"
  putStrLn "Anything"
else return ()
```

Because this pattern is quite common, there is a `when` combinator (in `Control.Monad`), which does precisely this

```
when (n > 0)
  do
    putStrLn "Hello"
    putStrLn "Anything"
```

or just simply

```
when (n > 0) (putStrLn "Hello" >> putStrLn "Anything")
```